# Match most punctuation using ModRewrite regex

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I'm using ModRewrite to send requests for

```
/2/Blog-Title
```

to

```
/?post=2&title=Blog-Title
```

Originally I used `([A-Za-z0-9-_/]+)`, but then realised that people were using lots of punctuation in their titles. I've gradually added lots more punctuation, but am feeling that this is the wrong way to go about this... I'm now using

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([A-Za-z0-9-_/\.\?\!':\&]+)$ /?post=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

How can I ignore any requirements for the title, and just match any text following the number? (I don't actually need the title= bit set, the text is really for SEO, not for internal working.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore title just do:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/.*$ /?post=$1 [L]
```

`.*` will match any string after `/` so it will matches anythong like:

```
/2/lores-ipsum_etc356
```

Comment: Oh yeah! I always miss the obvious!